# Menu responsivo com CSS, HTML e JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, layout-responsivo

Estou fazendo um menu responsivo usando o visual studio. Porém, quando estou deixando a página em 768px, os itens (inicio, missão, sobre...) que deveriam estar quando eu clicasse no menu hambuguer, não aparece.

código

```js
    const navSlide = () => {
        const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
        const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
        //Fazendo aparecer os itens
        const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
        
        //Fazendo o clique do menu funcionar
        burger.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
             nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    
             //Animações links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => { 
            if(link.style.animation){
                link.style.animation = '';
            }else{
                link.style.animation = `navlinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index/7+1.5}s`  
    
            }
        });
        //Transformando em X
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    
    
        });
    
    
    }
    
    navSlide();
```

```css
    *{
        margin: 0px;
        /*Distancia entre os itens*/
        padding: 0px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    nav{
        display:flex;
        /*Jogar os itens para o canto da página*/
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        min-height: 8vh;
        /*Mudando a cor de fundo do menu*/
        background-color: rgb(40, 113, 122);
        /*Fonte do menu*/
        font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .logo{
        /*Mudando a cor da fonte do nome*/
        color: white;
        /*Deixando o texto formatado*/
        text-transform: uppercase;
        /*Mudando o espaçamento das letras*/
        letter-spacing: 5px;
        /*Tamaho da letra*/
        font-size:20px;
    
    }
    .nav-links{
        /*Ajustando o tamanho e posição dos itens*/
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        width: 30%;
    
    }
    .nav-links li{
        /*Sumindo com os pontos que ficavam nos itens*/
        list-style: none;
    
    
    }
    .nav-links a{
        /*Mudando a cor dos itens*/
        color: white;
        /*Mudando o espaçamento das letras dos itens*/
        text-decoration: none;
        letter-spacing: 3px;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 14px;
    }
    .burger{
        /*Não deixando o menu hambuguer visivel */
        display:none;
        /*aparecendo a maozinha quando clica no menu hambuguer*/
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .burger div{
        /*Ajeitando o menu Hambuguer*/
        width: 25px;
        height: 3px;
        background-color:white;
        margin:5px;
        transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    /*Ajustando a altura*/
    @media screen and (max-width:1024px){
        .nav-links{
            width: 60%;
        }
    }
    /*Ajustando a altura minima*/
    @media screen and (max-width:768px){
        body{
           overflow-x: hidden;
        }
        /*ajustando os itens para se adequar a altura min.*/
        .nav-links{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            height: 92vh;
            top:8vh;
            /*Arrumando o menu hambuguer*/
            background-color: rgb(40, 113, 122);
            display:flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;
            /*Ajeitando a transição parar abrir o menu hambuguer*/
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
        }
        .nav-links li{
            opacity: 0;
        }
        .burger{
            /*para aparecer o menu hambuguer quando a tela tiver pequena*/
            display: block;
        }
    }
    /*Quando se clica no menu hambuguer, consegue abrir os itens*/
    .nav-active{
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
    /*Animações quando se clica no menu hamburguer*/
    @keyframes navLinkFade{
        from{
            opacity: 0;
            transform: translateX(50px);
        }
        to{
            opacity: 1;
            transform: translateX(0px);
        }
    }
    /*Transformando o menu em X*/
    .toggle .line1{
        transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
    }
    .toggle .line2{
        opacity: 0;
        
    }
    .toggle .line3{
        transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge" >
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
            <title>Novo Projeto</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
        
    
        <!--Menu responsivo-->
        <body>
            <nav>
                <div class="logo">
                    <h4>Teste</h4>
                </div>
    
                <ul class="nav-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Missão</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Portifólio</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!--Menu hambuguer-->
                <div class="burger">
                    <div class="line1"></div>
                    <div class="line2"></div>
                    <div class="line3"></div>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <script src="javs/app.js"></script>
    
        </body>
        
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Basicamente faltou esse código no seu CSS

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links.nav-active li {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Repare que nele quando a `.nav-links` está com a classe active eu mudo a `opacity` para `1` e o link passa a aparecer

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie-edge">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Novo Projeto</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
  * {
    margin: 0px;
    /*Distancia entre os itens*/
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  nav {
    display: flex;
    /*Jogar os itens para o canto da página*/
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 8vh;
    /*Mudando a cor de fundo do menu*/
    background-color: rgb(40, 113, 122);
    /*Fonte do menu*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  }

  .logo {
    /*Mudando a cor da fonte do nome*/
    color: white;
    /*Deixando o texto formatado*/
    text-transform: uppercase;
    /*Mudando o espaçamento das letras*/
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    /*Tamaho da letra*/
    font-size: 20px;

  }

  .nav-links {
    /*Ajustando o tamanho e posição dos itens*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 30%;

  }

  .nav-links li {
    /*Sumindo com os pontos que ficavam nos itens*/
    list-style: none;


  }

  .nav-links a {
    /*Mudando a cor dos itens*/
    color: white;
    /*Mudando o espaçamento das letras dos itens*/
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  .burger {
    /*Não deixando o menu hambuguer visivel */
    display: none;
    /*aparecendo a maozinha quando clica no menu hambuguer*/
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .burger div {
    /*Ajeitando o menu Hambuguer*/
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  /*Ajustando a altura*/
  @media screen and (max-width:1024px) {
    .nav-links {
      width: 60%;
    }
  }

  /*Ajustando a altura minima*/
  @media screen and (max-width:768px) {
    body {
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    /*ajustando os itens para se adequar a altura min.*/
    .nav-links {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      height: 92vh;
      top: 8vh;
      /*Arrumando o menu hambuguer*/
      background-color: rgb(40, 113, 122);
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      width: 50%;
      /*Ajeitando a transição parar abrir o menu hambuguer*/
      transform: translateX(100%);
      transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links li {
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger {
      /*para aparecer o menu hambuguer quando a tela tiver pequena*/
      display: block;
    }
  }

  /*Quando se clica no menu hambuguer, consegue abrir os itens*/
  .nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }

  /*Animações quando se clica no menu hamburguer*/
  @keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
      opacity: 0;
      transform: translateX(50px);
    }

    to {
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(0px);
    }
  }

  /*Transformando o menu em X*/
  .toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
  }

  .toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;

  }

  .toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
  }


  @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .nav-links.nav-active li {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
</style>
</head>


<!--Menu responsivo-->

<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="logo">
      <h4>Teste</h4>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a href="#">Início</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Sobre</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Missão</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portifólio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contatos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <!--Menu hambuguer-->
    <div class="burger">
      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <script src="javs/app.js"></script>

</body>

<script>
  const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    //Fazendo aparecer os itens
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');

    //Fazendo o clique do menu funcionar
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
      nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

      //Animações links
      navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
        if (link.style.animation) {
          link.style.animation = '';
        } else {
          link.style.animation = `navlinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index/7+1.5}s`

        }
      });
      //Transformando em X
      burger.classList.toggle('toggle');


    });


  }

  navSlide();
</script>

</html>
```